# Google analytics in Unity Android is not reliable

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I am using the Real Time report to test. In editor and ios, it behave quite well, it reacts in less than 10 seconds. but when i build in in android, it doesn't work. It detected my device ,and sometimes receive feedback after quite a while. But most of the time it just remain quiet. I feel that it may get signal while i open/close/reinstall the app, but not so sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some lines in GoogleAnalyticsV4.cs to force the system to use GoogleAnalyticsMPV3